# Wordpress - Vimeo frame stills

Tags: wordpress, plugins, vimeo

On my website i'm doing a portfolio with vimeo videos and I want to know if there's a plugin that make automatic frame stills from the video to the post, or if there's any way to do something like thumbnail creator on vimeo (you know, when you upload a video and you watch it and define this exact frame).

I want to end up with something like [this](http://lobomau.pt/lisb-on) when i have the video, then stills pictures from the video (automatic generator) and then the description.

Is there any plugin that can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually grab the generated poster frame using a bit of PHP

```
<?php 
    $hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/" . get_field('vimeo_url') . '.php' ));
?>
<a rel="lightbox" href="<?php echo "https://vimeo.com/" . get_field('vimeo_url'); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $hash[0]['thumbnail_large']; ?>" alt="">
</a>
```

just replace the get_field('vimeo_url') with your video ID and you're good.. this doesn't handle the download/writing to wordpress database.

Comment: Funkysoul, i have already a plugin to grab the thumbnail from vimeo and put it on wordpress, i want something that i can choose some video frame stills like i have show on the link up.

Comment: Sorry mate, got your question wrong.. 
There is none that I know of.. normally people do that beforehand as quality is normally much higher than from an online source

Comment: Thanks anyway! I'll wait maybe someone can give me some advice :)